# Shell script to iterate through sub-directories of a directory and execute a command

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compile each and every file in a directory as well as its sudirectories and directories of that subdirectories. So the basic idea is to compile all the files in that project. For that i have to write a shell script.

**My code**

`cd pathtomaindirectory

gcc *.c`

In this i have to run the that command on all the subdirectory files with .c extensions. So how do i use a for loop to it. I'm new to shell script

Thank You

Comment: Why c tag? Its related to shell scripting. Related to c is you are using .c files

Comment: There are zillions of questions that demonstrate how to list files recursively and perform an action.  Did you try searching?

Comment: Ya but dint get a clear picture about it.

Comment: Set up apropiate Makefiles, and use make. Or whatever your favorite build system might be. Much more robust and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
cd path/to/main/directory
find . -name '*.c' -exec gcc -c {} \;
gcc -o app *.o
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash, enable recursive glob wildcards:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
gcc **.c
```